# How can I get a param using regex in a nginx server block?

Tags: regex, nginx, server, block

I'm trying to get a param(h=1500 for example) via regex in a server block in an nginx server but it's not working. My last try was this:

```
location ~ "^/app/events/(?<eventid>\d+)/(?<image>.+)?h=(?<height>\d+)$" { ...... }
```

Here you can check and it works: https://regex101.com/r/kP9eY9/1

But in my server block file it does't.

If I try something like this, it works:

```
location ~ "^/app/events/(?<eventid>\d+)/(?<image>.+)/(?<height>\d+)$" { ...... }
```

Instead a param like "h=300", I just use a "/300" and I can get the value in my server block file.

I'm not a expert using regex so I can't see if there is something wrong. I need your help guys! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to escape eqiality sign? I mean `h\=`.
Also `?` after your `(?<image>.+)`. First request has it, but second doesn't. According to example string in provided link, I guess you wanted to set it as a character, not as special symbol, so use `(?<image>.+)\?`

Comment: I did try `(?<image>.+)\?` but this also doesn't work. And yes, I want it as a character like a get parameter `?foo=bar`. I don't know if I did undertand, do I also need to escape the eqiality sign? Like `\?h\=(?<height>\d+)`

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html):

> locations of all types test only a URI part of request line without
>   arguments

which means the `?` and anything that follows it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Richard mentioned, you can't use request arguments in locations regexps.

If you need to work with request arguments in your nginx config you might use **$arg_** and/or **$args** syntax:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args

I.e

```
location / {
  if ($arg_param = 'someval') {
     # some code here
  }
}
```